# Binding breaks with nested ngInclude

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have list of tasks which may have subtasks and so on. This is nested structure and I don't want to load whole tree, I want load only root level and then load each branch by users demand. So I'm using nesting `ng-includes` and `ng-init` to pass list of taks and here is the template:

```
<div ng-repeat="task in tasks" class="task">
  {{task.name}}
  <a href ng-click="expand(task)">expand</a>
  <a href ng-click="remove(task, tasks)">remove</a>
  <div ng-show="task.subtasks" ng-init="tasks = task.subtasks" ng-include="'tasks.html'"></div>
</div>
```

Controller:

```
app.controller 'MainCtrl', ($scope, $http) ->
  $http.get('tasks.json').then (tasks) ->
    $scope.tasks = tasks.data

  $scope.expand = (task) ->
    if !task.subtasks
      $http.get("subtasks.json").then (tasks) ->
        task.subtasks = tasks.data
    task.expanded = yes

  $scope.remove = (task, list) ->
    list = _.reject list, id:task.id
```

When user expand branch and sub-tasks get loaded, it does not updates in view, so I assume that ng-include create new child scope. How I can handle this problem?

Here is plunk for this http://plnkr.co/edit/AkIZV1PkD5a3AzCBen8R

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not conversant with coffee script. But the problem that you have is that, the ng-init where you assign `task=task.subtasks` does not work because during your ng-init the task.subTasks is undefined due to the async remote call.

One way to fix this would be when you get task data set each of the  subtasks array to empty `[]`.

Then when you get subTasks data fill this array rather than reassigning. Such as

```
//For each subtask item from server result

//task.subtasks.push(subtask);
```

Comment: Here is the plunk where I tested your guess http://plnkr.co/edit/jUSli6m1uz63BJj7Rom3 but this does not help. I think the fact that `task.subtasks` is undefined is not a problem, $scope.tasks is also undefined at some point but this does not lead to problems...

Comment: If you look at generated html in, is generating the child, but they are hidden.